# How to pass variables in a paramter of an html component with django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm today working on a django porject composed of only one application (an encyclopedia), but I am facing some struggles.

I have a view named index that is displaying all the encyclopedias that the user can access to. On each file, I want to add a link to can redirect the user to the concerned encyclopedia.

To do that, in my index view, I am calling a function that lists all the encyclopedias that we can have access to. This list will be used for rendering an html page.

The problem that I am facing is on this html page named index.html. I am trying to pass the name of each encyclopedia in the href parameter for my link. Here is my html code:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href ="/{{entry}}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

P.S: my django project is based on a base code provided by : https://cs50.harvard.edu/web/2020/projects/1/wiki/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was finally that I had to remove the slash. It is working with this code :

```
<li><a href ={{entry}}>{{ entry }}</a></li>
```

Thank you @AryanJassl for helping.

Answer (score 1):

In your urls.py file, put this code in:

```
path("<str:entry>/", views.display_entry, name="display_entry")
```

The `<str:>` determines the variable type and the text after that is the name of the variable. You can do something like this in the view:

```
def display_entry(request, entry):
```

Note that the name in the urls.py and the view should be the same.

Comment: and how can I add it in my html link component please ?
But I don't understand how does asking for a string in the url is going to let me displaying my encyclopedias as links. Here is how my urlpatterns look linke if it can explain in a better way how is my project organizing:
`urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("Home", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:title>", views.find_page, name="find"),
]`